# recursively find a string with a wildcard in Word Doc files, output to text file, how to get rid of Word garbage?

Tags: windows, command-line, ms-word, find

Here's what I'm trying to do:

1. using cmd.exe, go to a mounted windows network drive
2. there is a hierarchy of folders in the starting directory with .doc files in them in which I want to search for a string that starts with "CCMPD" and then has unique numbers after that (defect numbers).
3. The hierarchy is not consistent, that is, some folders have the .doc at the first level, others have some more folders under them where the doc is.
4. Output each matching line to a file.

I came up with the command line command:

> findstr /S "CCMPD" *.doc > D:\Data\FIND.txt

That actually works (I'm pretty proud of that) but the file is filled with the garbage that lives in a Word doc, and I can't figure out how to filter it out. I can't even paste the output in here because they're not printable characters but you have probably all seen them before.

How can I create a find command that can filter out the Word garbage and output to an easily readable file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using the [Strings tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897439).  This will extract out the strings and get rid of the garbage.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to: 1 - remove duplicates 2 - remove the file name at the beginning of each line 3 - remove the text before and after the word containing "CCMPD" - I just want the unique defect ID that starts with CCMPD and has unique numbers after it, but could do without any other information.

Comment: Have you taken a look at [Windows Powershell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd835506(VS.85).aspx)?  You might want to write a script for that tool to do what you need.  Or you could always use something like [Perl](http://www.perl.org/) too of course.